# Why am I getthing a Response Code: 200 when I put in all of the <meta og: in properly

Tags: facebook, metatag

Here is what I get when I us the facebook debugger:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.towertheatermiami.com%2FTeventDetails.aspx%3FSeriesId%3D8874

Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    http://www.towertheatermiami.com/TeventDetails.aspx?SeriesId=8874

I realize that this page is not posting to facebook properly when recommending or writing a comment. The image and content doesn't come in at all under my facebook profile.

Answer (score 1):

Response code 200 means that Facebook was able to scrape your page.

The problem that I am seeing with your URL is that it returns a 404 error and you redirect to a custom 404.  Facebook is scraping the tags from your custom error page.